# Django-Haystack: should_update doesn't appear to trigger with RealtimeSignalProcessor?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a model that has a boolean field that states whether the model object is active or not. I basically wish for Haystack to ignore any objects with active=False. This works fine for a complete reindex using:

```
def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    return ExampleModel.objects.filter(active=True)
```

However when an object is updated and the index is realtime updated and not completely reindexed, such as when changing an object to inactive, the following doesn't work and additionally seems to be uncalled:

```
def should_update(self, instance):
    if instance.active:
        return True
    self.remove_object(instance)
    return False
```

I want the object to be removed from the index when it is marked as inactive, however on updating the object to inactive it remains in the index affecting facet counts etc. I checked with using manage.py update_index and the should_update code doesnt seem to run?

For info i am using haystack dev and elasticsearch latest stable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try running `python manage.py update_index --remove`?

Comment: Drewness, Yes this works a treat - however I wish to use RealTimeSignalProcessor which means the index would be out of sync unless this was run? - Also, it worked removing one object but then when theres nothing to index it still leaves items in the index?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, [`should_update()`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/914a9baf/haystack/indexes.py#L262&#L272) returns True by default which means reindex. Additionally, [`remove_object()`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/914a9baf/haystack/indexes.py#L219&#L228) is attached to the class's post-delete hook, which could be why it's not being called since you're not deleting the record.

You should be able to trigger the index removal by slightly altering your code like this:

```
def should_update(self, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.active:
        return True
    else:
        self.remove_object(instance, **kwargs)
        return False
```

or the reverse:

```
def should_update(self, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.active:
        self.remove_object(instance, **kwargs)
    return instance.active
```

Another option would be to create a CRON script that does:

```
import haystack
from yourapp.models import ExampleModel

for obj in ExampleModel.objects.filter(active=False):
    haystack.site.remove_object(obj)
```

This could also be used by the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal in Django.

Fine print: I have **not** tested *any* of this code. It is *theoretical* based on the information provided in the question.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and as before it doesn't even seem to be called. I've seen some code in a CMS project identical to my code that should work, and therefore I cannot work out why its being ignore. I updated to latest dev version and its still the same - the should_update code is not running at all?

Answer (score 1):

1. create a signals.py file in your app directory
2. edit signals.py:

   ```
   from haystack import signals
   from .models import Product
   from haystack.exceptions import NotHandled

   class ProductUpdateSignalProcessor(signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor):

       def handle_save(self, sender, instance, **kwargs):
           if isinstance(instance, Product):
               using_backends = self.connection_router.for_write(instance=instance)
               for using in using_backends:
                   try:
                       index = self.connections[using].get_unified_index().get_index(sender)
                       if instance.active:
                           index.update_object(instance, using=using)
                       else:
                           index.remove_object(instance, using=using)
                   except NotHandled:
                       print(NotHandled.message)
           else:
               super(ProductUpdateSignalProcessor, self).handle_save(sender, instance, **kwargs)
   ```
3. edit settings.py:

   ```
   HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'products.signals.ProductUpdateSignalProcessor'
   ```